# How to loop through an S3 bucket to copy certain list of folders from S3 bucket to local server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, regex-lookarounds

```
Have over 2000+ folders reside in S3 bucket. I do not want to copy all folders to my local server. 
Is there a way or a script to loop through to copy 200 folders out of 2000+ folders from that particular bucket. for eg.
```

Need to copy over 200-400 folders out of 2000+ from s3 bucket, is there a regex group capture or script to automate to copy certain list of folders

```
input.....

faob/
halb/
mcgb/
mgvb/
nxhb/
ouqb/
pdyb/
qwdb/

output...

ouqb/
pdyb/
qwdb/

aws s3 cp s3://s3-bucket/* /tmp/
```

Comment: It might be easier for you to write your own script to determine which objects to copy. For example, a Python program could loop through the list of objects, apply logic for which files are desired and then download the objects. Alternatively, you write a shell script to loop through a file containing a list of objects to copy, then call the AWS CLI to copy the specific files.

Comment: All the folders endswith "b" like listed below do you have any idea on how to achieve that 
input(faob/ halb/ mcgb/ mgvb/ nxhb/ ouqb/ pdyb/ qwdb/)
output(ouqb/ pdyb/ qwdb/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple `--include` parameters to specify multiple input locations.

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name /local/folder --recursive --exclude "*" --include "faob/*" --include "halb/*" --include "mcgb/*"
```

But you can't have multiple destination folders.

hope this helps.

Comment: That will work but i need to copy over 200-400 folders out of 2000+ from s3 bucket, is there a regex group capture or script to automate to copy certain list of folders

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://my-bucket /tmp/ --exclude "*" --include "*b/*"
```

For information about using wildcards in `aws s3 cp`, see: [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: All my folders endswith "b" for example ouqb/ pdyb/ qwdb/ is bout 2000+ and needs copy 200-400 to my local /tmp is there any script to achieved that